# write plist files incrementally

Tags: ios, plist

I have a `NSMutableArray`, and I write it to a plist file using `writeToFile: atomically:`. The elements in the array are all property list objects.

Then in my iPhone App, I meet a case: when the `NSMutableArray` needs to add an object and I also want to update the plist file. Now what I do is to call `writeToFile: atomically:` when an new one is added.

However when the code>NSMutableArray has a large mount of data, it must be in poor performance. SO I wonder how to write the newly added element to the existed plist file.

Thanks.

PS: the business logic is:

When the user does some action,like sending a new message or add a new photo, I'll make a record of user,message/image data and time(all is property list objects). The Action can be happen everywhere, and I didn't create the array to check the actions always (and it is in no need). Of course I use sqilte to do it, but I also need a plist file, so that user's friends can download it whenever they want. The friends need no request from the user and just download it. So I plan to keep an up-to-date plist file. 
That's all why I need it.

Comment: Have you measured with Instruments that you get poor performance? Plists are amazingly fast, so unless you KNOW it's slow, don't worry about it.

Comment: @mortenfast, I didn't measured with instrument but I felt it.  In the array, each element is a customized object and it has 8 attributes(NSString,NSDate,NSData), one of which is NSData created from a UIImage. so,you can imagine...

Answer (score 1):

If there comes a stage when `plist` files turn in poor performance and you've to worry about adding the data incrementally, you must actually be looking at [`Core Data`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Comment: I need the plist file so that it can be downloaded by others.

Comment: If the `plist` is large, it does matter if you need to send the entire thing over. Shouldn't you be serving the `diff` instead? Identify what content the other user need given their current state and pass just that information. Just a thought. I don't know your use case so can't comment much.

Comment: +1 on this. If the data set is very large (and has lots of binary content), plists are not the way to go.

Comment: how to using diff on plist file?

Comment: No I wasn't talking about diff on a plist file. I was talking about generating diff of core data based on what the other user needs. However since it is an array. You can identify the chunk of array that the other user doesn't have and generate a plist based on that chunk and send that plist over.